# How to select multiple columns in subquery using JPA Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria

I am trying to write the below query using JPA criteria but I am not able to select the multiple columns in a subquery.

```
SELECT a.id, a.firstName, a.lastName
FROM PORTRAIT a
JOIN (SELECT firstName, lastName
FROM PORTRAIT 
GROUP BY firstName, lastName
HAVING count(id) > 1 ) b
ON b.firstName = a.firstName
AND b.lastName = a.lastName
ORDER BY a.lastName asc

or

SELECT a.id, a.FIRSTNAME, a.LASTNAME
FROM PORTRAIT a where exists (
    SELECT b.firstName, b.lastName
    FROM PORTRAIT b 
    WHERE b.firstName = a.firstName
    AND b.lastName = a.lastName
    GROUP BY b.firstName, b.lastName
    HAVING count(b.id) > 1
)
```

I stuck in the middle of my implementation below where I am not able to find out how to select multiple columns in the subquery. Please see my comment in the code (at 3rd line).

```
    
        Subquery<PortraitVO> portraitSubQuery = criteriaQuery.subquery(PortraitVO.class);
        Root<PortraitVO> portraitRoot = portraitSubQuery.from(PortraitVO.class);
        portraitSubQuery.select(portraitRoot); // Here I want to select multiple columns
        portraitSubQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(portraitRoot.get(RestServiceConstants.FIRST_NAME), root.get(RestServiceConstants.FIRST_NAME)), criteriaBuilder.equal(portraitRoot.get(RestServiceConstants.LAST_NAME), root.get(RestServiceConstants.LAST_NAME))));
        
        List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        columnNames.add(RestServiceConstants.FIRST_NAME);
        columnNames.add(RestServiceConstants.LAST_NAME);
    
        List<Expression<?>> columnNamesExpression = columnNames.stream().map(x -> portraitRoot.get(x))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
        portraitSubQuery.groupBy(columnNamesExpression);
        portraitSubQuery.having(criteriaBuilder.gt(criteriaBuilder.count(portraitRoot), 1));
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Why would you select multiple column in a subselect in an exists clause?

Comment: @JensSchauder I need to do the GROUP BY by both first name and last name. That's why I included both of them in the select.

Answer (score 1):

JPA does not allow to select multiple expressions in a subquery and in fact, selecting anything in a subquery that is wrapped with `exists` is pointless. Just select a constant value e.g. the integer `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense to select two columns in a subselect used inside an `exists`. And I'm not sure if it is legal.

Just use one of the columns or a literal.

Comment: I need to do the GROUP BY by both first name and last name. That's why I included both of them in the select. 

Can you please provide me more info on literal.